# Cant control computer via apple remote desktop

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I'm trying to use Apple Remote Desktop to access my computer at work. I forgot to give myself permissions via the gui and I am now trying to set it up via SSH. I've logged in to the computer and ran

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users evan -privs -all -restart -agent -menu
```

based on what [I found here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2370).

The output of the command was

```
Starting...
Activated Remote Management.
Stopped ARD Agent.
Stopped VNC Server.
Stopped RFB Register MDNS
evan: Set user remote control privileges.
evan: Set user remote access.
Done.
```

Which lead me think it was set up properly and just to be safe I then ran

```
sudo reboot
```

However I'm still missing something. From home I am able to 'Observe' (the computer is currently at the login screen - hope that doesn't make a difference?) but when I try to 'Control' it says "You are not authorized to control this computer."

What simple mistake am I making?? :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend double checking the settings when you're physically at the machine and make sure you have enabled Control.

You'll find it under the Sharing preference pane, under the Remote Management service.  the `-privs -all` flags should have turned on control and observe, according to the `man` page and the online docs I have bookmarked.

You could always try setting it directly through kickstart again:

`sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users evan -privs -ControlObserve`

But I doubt it'll change much.